# Do photons show electromagnetic interactions?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light

As gravity can bend light, can an electric or magnetic field do the same. Matter cannot pass through matter because of electromagnetic forces. Light cannot pass through matter in some cases as matter absorbs and emits them back. But would it be possible to reflect light only using electromagnetic forces?

Comment: Matter can not pass trough matter because of electrical forces, not electromagnetical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photons are force carriers of the electromagnetic force. You can view photons like free particles moving toward matter and if they collide with matter, the photons are annihilated, but Show their cause by changing energy and momentum of the matter particles like electrons.

An (external) electromagnetic force field is carried also by photons behaving as the same as stated above. Another photon coming from light does not interact with the photons coming from the (external) force field, so the answer to your question is no.

But: In Quantum Electrodynamics, the vacuum is considered as consisting of particles popping in and out of existence. This fact modifies the behavior of photons in order of Planck's constant $\hbar$ (e.g. photons may interact among each other effectively). However, because this constant is extremely small and we live on large length and time scales where Quantum uncertainties can be neglected, the Quantum behavior of photons can be neglected for everyday life phenomena.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. the electromagnetic field is what gives rise to light - light particles (photons) are oscillations in said field.